# Async I/O for DataSet in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

What is the equivalent for async I/O on a DataSet in Flink ? For **DataStream** its basically **AsyncDataStream**.

Doing a blocking call in the map function ?

Are their any best practices ?

Comment: I have 20K remote streams where i have to make an HTTP GET call per minute and process the results. My first idea was to map over all streams and make the HTTP call. But this is not very perfomant since the map call is blocking. I want to make the map call parallel so it can use my multiple workers in the cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd implement that with a `RichMapPartitionFunction`, which provides an iterator over the input and a collector to emit results.

Since the DataSet API does not need to integrate with the checkpointing mechanism and respect the order of records and timestamps, the implementation shouldn't be very involved although `MapPartitionFunction` does not provide any async-specific tooling.

Comment: Can the RichMapPartitionFunction run in parallel on other workers in the cluster ?

Comment: Yes, it Flink streams the each partition into a separate `mapPartition()` function call. All partitions are concurrently processed in parallel.